# Taking function from an input using lambda

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to do numeral integration in python, and want to make a state-machine where you ask the user for method, function, ranges and intervals. But i can't seem to get it working, it just keeps asking me to input another function.

I'm a novice programmer, so i've only tried the code shown below.

```
def venstre_sum(start,end,inv,func):
    return sum([((end-start)/inv)*func(((end-start)/inv)*i+start) for i in range(inv)])

def hoejre_sum(start,end,inv,func):
    return sum([((end-start)/inv)*func(((end-start)/inv)+((end-start)/inv)*i+start) for i in range(inv)])

def trapez(start,end,inv,func):
    returnv  = (venstre_sum(start,end,inv,func)+hoejre_sum(start,end,inv,func))/2
    return returnv

def midtsum(start,end,inv,func):
    return sum([((end-start)/inv)*func(((end-start)/inv)*(i+0.5)+start) for i in range(inv)])


while True:

    state = input("Which method would you like to use? (v,h,t,m,s)")
    f = lambda x: eval(input("Funktion:"))
    ranges1 = int(input("Give a x0:"))
    ranges2 = int(input("Give a xn:"))
    inv = int(input("Amount of intervals:"))
    h = (ranges2-ranges1)/inv

    if state == "v":
        print("###########VENSTRESUMS-AREAL:")
        print(inv,"intervaller",f.__name__,"(x) A=",venstre_sum(ranges1,ranges2,inv,f))
```

I wanted it to print my area under function, but it just keeps asking me for another function. Sorry i cont know how to paste my code. :/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
f = lambda x: eval(input("Funktion:"))
```

is the exact equivalent of

```
def f(x):
    return eval(input("Funktion:"))
```

Then you pass `f` to `venstre_sum`, which calls `f`, which executes `input("Funktion")`, pass the result to `eval()` and returns the result.

IOW this is the expected behaviour - even if not what *you* expected ;-)

First point here: do NOT use `eval()`, and specially not on user inputs (unless you want the first script kiddie to take control of your program of course).

Now you didn't post anything about what someone is supposed to type as "function", but if it's the name of an existing function, the solution is quite simple and a very common pattern: build a dict of allowed functions and get the function from this, ie:

```
def area(x):
    return x * x

def spam(x):
    return x * "spam"

# etc

FUNCTIONS = {
    "area": area,
    "spam": spam,
    # ...
    }

# and then:
funcname = input("Funktion:")
f = FUNCTIONS[funcname]
```